# Get geo cordinates from only with autocomplete api call android

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to implement an android app where users can enter their city , and I need to add a marker to that city user input.

So far I was stumbling upon google auto-complete API , then I got autocomplete part working . But now I need to place a marker and for that and I need geo-code of the city that user entered , but as I understand google API for auto-complete only provide address or city , no geo-codinates.

Since I am fairly new to android development , can someone assist me with this situation and let me know whether there is a method of getting geo-codinates from single auto-complete API call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "you can convert an address to the corresponding geographic coordinates. This process is called geocoding"

Android come with some tools for geo data manipulation as the Geocoder class, I don't know if it is the most efficient solution, but you can try it.

When you obtain the address description with autocomplete api you can call a service to do the geocoding and get the geographic data, then you can show it in your map.

[You should read this!](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)

[This is an example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationAddress)